# upgrade fedora from 29 to 30

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I wanna update fedora from 29 to 30 and I used regular commands to update fedora that u can find them in fedoramagazine or other websites listed in google. but I have got an error after I entered:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

and fedora answered:

```
Error: system is not ready for upgrade
```

I can not find anything related to this error. system is not ready!!!

is there any suggestion or related experience? thanks in advance

Comment: Actually searching for that error gives a lot of results in Google. How come you can't find anything?

Comment: the results show the regular way to upgrade the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The probable cause for this badly-worded error message is that some packages
have broken dependencies.

Fedora Wiki article "DNF system upgrade" contains a section about
[Using distro-sync to resolve dependency issues](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade#Using_distro-sync_to_resolve_dependency_issues),
where it counsels the following command for making the installed packages to be
exactly the same version as in the currently enabled repositories,
even if it meant downgrading some packages:

```
sudo dnf distro-sync
```

If this is not enough, a stronger variant will remove packages for which
dependencies can't be satisfied:

```
sudo dnf distro-sync --allowerasing
```